# How to show formally that $\Bbb B_{n+1}\cap K$ is not homeomorphic to $\Bbb B_k$ for any $k\le n$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

This question is on the context of euclidean spaces.

With slight abuse of notation let $K:=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R:|x|^2=y^2\}\subset\Bbb R^{n+1}$ and $\Bbb B_k$ an open ball centered at zero of radius $1$ in $\Bbb R^k$.

Then I want to show that $\Bbb B_{n+1}\cap K$ is not homeomorphic to $\Bbb B_k$ for any $k\le n$. For $n=1$ we have that $\Bbb B_2\cap K$ have the form of a "X", so is intuitive to see that this "X" subset of the plane cannot be homeomorphic to any open interval in $\Bbb R$.

But I dont know exactly how I can formalize this idea, neither in the general setting of $n$. Some help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point $0\in K\cap \mathbb{B}_n$ for any $n>1$.

$$ K\cap \mathbb{B}_n\setminus \{0\} = K_+\cap \mathbb{B}_n \cup K_-\cap \mathbb{B}_n $$

where $K_{+} = \{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R:|x|^2=y^2, y >0\}$ and $K_-$ is defined similarly $(y<0)$. 
So $K\cap \mathbb{B}_n\setminus \{0\}$ it is *not connected* hence it cannot be homeomorphic to  $\mathbb{B}_k\setminus \{p\}$ for $k\geq 1$.
The only possibility left to esclude is that $K\cap \mathbb{B}_n$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{B}_1$ but since $n> 1$, you can find  $U\subset K\cap \mathbb{B}_n$, such that $U$ is homeomorphic to $\text{int}(\mathbb{B}_2)$, and $\mathbb{B}_1$ does not contain anything homeomorphic to $\mathbb{B}_2$ (it would be an interval  but then if you remove a point you would end with a disconnected set).

Comment: oh, I see... the trick is quit a point on both sides and compare, right?

Comment: You are right indeed! You can do it also multiple times to exclude the case n=1